# Error installing Entity Framework package

Tags: entity-framework, nuget-package

I got a strange error when trying to install the latest version of EntityFramework(4.1.10715.0) from the package manager:

> The 'schemaVersion' attribute is not declared.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to install the [latest NuGet version](http://nuget.org/)